# What do the sex noises in the movie "Pi" (1998) symbolize?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, pi

In the movie *Pi* (1998) there are a couple of scenes were we hear Devi moaning through the walls. The moaning occurs during two "episodes" (headaches).

Generally speaking, sex is something that is sought after. It's usually associated with good feelings, but for Max the sex noises cause his headaches to get worse. Is this scene showing how Max doesn't easily relate to other people? Is this scene showing how "non human" Max is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devi is everything that Max is not--lively, emotional, sexual. Her vivaciousness and kind nature serve as a painful reminder to the warmth and pleasures of the real world that Max has barricaded himself from.